# Sync a particular depo from multiple depo projects in Perforce

Tags: perforce

How can I sync only 1 particular branch from my depo in P4.

Below command needs the file name:

```
p4 sync -n -f //depot/...filename
```

But I want to sync entire branch & I've multiple branches in my laptop. How can I specifically tell P4 to sync only a particular depo branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ... in the command line you show means, roughly, "every subtree", so it syncs that filename in all branches under your depot. Instead you can give the full path -- either in local, or depot form -- of the file you actually want:

```
# sync everything in a branch
p4 sync -n -f //depot/path/to/branch/...    

# sync only one file in a branch
p4 sync -n -f //depot/path/to/branch/.../filename.ext
```

Comment: p4 sync -n -f //depot/path/to/branch/... doesn't seem to work

Comment: Oh -- the -n option means "tell me what you would do, but don't actually do it" - a dry run.

Comment: You typically should not need the -f flag to sync.  That is a "force" sync and will deliver files from the server to client regardless of whether that file is already synced or not.  -f is typically used to get past "can't clobber writable file" errors on sync, or problems where the file was deleted on the client by hand and you need to get it back.  In most cases though, I wouldn't use the -f flag as that merely makes the sync of a depot area take longer as you are syncing everything in the depot.